# HTML5 Web Storage - Storing JSON Data and then retrieving it

Tags: javascript, html

On the home page of my app, I'm making an AJAX call to get a large amount of data that will be needed in various parts of my app. The call looks as follows:

```
var url = "/Taxonomy/GetTaxonomyList/"
$.getJSON(url, { includeOverrides: true }, function (jsonData) {
}).success(function (jsonData) {
    sessionStorage.taxonomyWithOverrides = jsonData;
}).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
   ...
});
```

This AJAX call is calling a C# method that is returning a JSONResult. This part seems to be working ok because I am getting the data I expect.

In another page I'm attempting to read this data as follows:

```
var taxonomy = [];

if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined") {
    jsonData = sessionStorage.taxonomyWithOverrides;

    $.each(jsonData, function (key, data) {
        taxonomy.push(data.species);
    })
} else {
    alertify.alert("Storage not supported");
}
```

However, I'm getting the following JavaScript error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '182782' in [object Object],
[object Object],...

Clearly I'm doing something wrong. But, I don't have a great deal of experience with this so I'm not sure where to look.

Here is my c# method that returns the JSON data:

```
public JsonResult GetTaxonomyList(bool includeOverrides)
{
    try
    {
        var taxonomyList = this.TaxonomyData.GetList(this.AccountRowId,0,string.Empty,true, includeOverrides)
            .Select(row => row.CommonName + " - " + row.ScientificName)
            .ToList();

        var jsonList = (from species in taxonomyList
                        select new { species }
                        ).OrderBy(row => row.species);

        return Json(jsonList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    catch (System.Exception exception)
    {
        ...;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You stored a string, when you get it back from storage you have to parse it back to an object, as `$.each` doesn't work on strings, but objects and arrays

```
var taxonomy = [];

if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined") {
    jsonData = JSON.parse( sessionStorage.taxonomyWithOverrides  || '[]');

    $.each(jsonData, function (key, data) {
        taxonomy.push(data.species);
    })
} else {
    alertify.alert("Storage not supported");
}
```

I'm assuming you have a stringify() method that is chainable, otherwise change

```
jsonData.stringify();
```

to

```
JSON.stringify(jsonData);
```

Comment: Thank you. But when I tried this, I get the following error on the line with the parse statement:  "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o"

Comment: Then the string stored is not  valid JSON. I added a fallback if sessionStorage returns `undefined` but it won't work on a non-json string. Does your stringify method produce JSON.

Comment: I've included the C# method that generates the JSON data. Perhaps I'm not storing it correctly in the sessionStorage call?

Comment: I have no idea what `jsonData.stringify();` produces, that is a custom method. Did you try using `JSON.stringify` instead.

Comment: I figured it out. Your answer helped me to discover how to proceed to make it work. Thank you.